# Access and print form option name="" using php

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to display the month and corresponding birthstone using php.  I used an associative array to dynamically populate options for a select and I've gotten so far as to print the birthstone, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the option names to display the month as well. This is for an assignment I've already handed in (of which, what I have satisfies the requirements.  I'm looking to figure out the non-required part.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on accessing the values for option name=""

Thanks!

```
    <html>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Birthstones by Month</h1>

        <p>Select a Month from the dropdown to reveal your birthstone</p>

        <form action="birthstone.php" method="post">
<?php

$months = array ( 'January' => 'Garnet', 'February' => 'Amethyst',  'March' => 'Aquamarine',  'April' => 'Diamond',  'May' => 'Emerald', 
 'June' => 'Pearl',  'July' => 'Ruby',  'August' => 'Peridot',  'September' => 'Sapphire',  'October' => 'Tourmaline',  'November' => 'Citrine',
   'December' => 'Tanzanite');
print "<select name='bstones'>";

foreach($months as $month => $stone) {

    print "print <option value='".$stone ."'name='".$month ."'>" . $month . "</option>";;

}

    print "</select> <br />";

?>
<button type="submit" name="sumbit" value="submit">Reveal my Birthstone</button>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['bstones']))//this is validating the selection
{

    $bstones = $_POST['bstones']; //this is assigning a variable name to the option values from the select 
    print "Your birthstone is <b>$bstones</b>";
}
//I really wanted to display the month selected as well as the stone, but I could not figure out how to get the month to print out.  When I try to google this issue,
//I only see instructions on how to access the option value, not the name.

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array keys as the option values, not the array values.

```
print "<select name='months'>";
foreach($months as $month => $stone) {
    print "print <option value='".$month ."'name='".$month ."'>" . $month . "</option>";;
}
print "</select>";
```

Then you can use this to look up the stone in the array.

```
if (isset($_POST['months']))//this is validating the selection
{

    $month = $_POST['months'];
    print "Your birth month is <b>$month</b>, your birthstone is <b>{$months[$month]}</b>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked.  I did have to change if (isset($_POST['bstones'])) to if (isset($_POST['months']))

I am curious though, why $stone was replaced with $month for <option value?

Answer (score 0):

The `select` has a `name` property, but `option` tags don't. So you can't get the name of the option.

What you should do is set value of the option to the month name, and then on `birthstone.php`, use the `$months` array to get the birthstone name associated to that month.

So:

```
foreach($months as $month => $stone) {
    print "<option value='".$month ."'>" . $month . "</option>";
}
```

And then:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bstones']))//this is validating the selection
{
    $month = $_POST['bstones']; //this is assigning a variable name to the option values from the select 
    print "You selected $month, so your birthstone is <b>". $months[$month] ."</b>";
}
```